# Has Hashim Amla's religion directly affected his finances or game?

Tags: cricket, history, finances, uniform

I need to clarify the below two things about the former South African Test Captain Hashim Amla.

> - He is being fined 500$ per month for not wearing Castle Logo in his    jersey.
> - He was fasting during his [triple century](http://www.espncricinfo.com/england-v-south-africa-2012/content/story/573524.html) against England.

I want to know whether these two things are true or not. I need reliable references in the answer, since different sites reveal different things about the above.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- Hashim Amla pays a fine for not wearing Castle logo: **FALSE**

Reference: CSA's official Facebook page confirms this [here](https://www.facebook.com/CricketSouthAfrica/posts/10151329288049351).

[image: CSA comment on Hashim Amla's fine.]

- Hashim Amla was fasting during the triple century against England: **FALSE**

Reference: Cricinfo [commentary](http://www.espncricinfo.com/england-v-south-africa-2012/engine/match/534225.html?innings=2;page=2;view=commentary) during this game says the following: (see 76th over)

> Firdose Moonda, our South Africa correspondent at The Oval, confirms that Amla (and Imran Tahir) are only fasting on non-match days.

Until there is evidence to the contrary, I consider CSA and Cricinfo's word to be reliable enough.